# using two indices to refer to subplot axes when either the number of rows or columns is unity

Tags: python, matplotlib

It is possible to refer to different subplots using two indices to index their axes as in the following example

```
rows = 2
cols = 2
f, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols)
x = np.arange(12)
y = xdata**2
plotFunction(x,y,ax,0,1)

def plotFunction(xdata, ydata, ax, i, j):
    ax[i,j].plot(xdata, ydata, marker='o', label='quadratic')
```

however if either rows or cols = 1 pyplot does not permit the use of two indices.  This precludes the generic use of my plotting function that relies on double index plotting.  So the following won't work

```
rows = 1
cols = 2
f, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols)
x = np.arange(12)
y = xdata**2
plotFunction(x,y,ax,0,1)
```

Comment: Try reshaping `ax`:  `ax = ax.reshape(rows, cols)`.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the 'squeeze=False' option when calling subplots.

```
rows = 1
cols = 2
f, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, squeeze=False)
x = np.arange(12)
y = xdata**2
plotFunction(x,y,ax,0,1,label='quadratic')

def plotFunction(xdata, ydata, ax, i, j, label):
ax[i,j].plot(xdata, ydata, marker='o', label=label)
```

This permits [row,col] indexing in all cases.